# .NET Serilization/Marshaling similar to Apache Cammel: Bindy?

Tags: c#, parsing, frameworks

Is there something similar to Apache Cammel: Bindy in the .Net world? I'm trying to avoid having to write something similar, but I may have no choice. Even bindy won't entirely work for me since I'm dealing with moderately complex flat files (actually MQ Messages) and I don't believe bindy has the notion of a discriminator.

The messages I'm dealing with are made up of \n separated 80 char ascii records. The first position contains a record type id, and for the actual data records the second position is a sub-type id. The message is hierarchical in that it contains a message header, batch header, data records, batch trailer, message trailer.

A simple example:

```
Axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
BxxxxxxxxxJIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
J1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
J1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
J1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
YxxxxxxxxxJI00003xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Zxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

...where A is the Message Header, B is the Batch Header - which contains a Type hint, J1 is a data record, Y is the batch trailer which contains the same type hint and a record count, and Z is the message Trailer.

A more complex example:

```
Axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
BxxxxxxxxxASxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
T1xxxxaaa00000000 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
T1xxxxbbb11111111 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
T3xxxxbbb11111111 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
T1xxxxccc22222222 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
T2xxxxccc22222222 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
T3xxxxccc22222222 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
YxxxxxxxxxAS000006xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Zxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

...where there are a variable number of sub-types related through the record key.

In all I'm dealing with about 25 different type/sub-types. From a business perspective the simple example always represents a single array of items, where each J1 will hold 4. In the more complex example T1, T2, ... Tx represents a single entity related by key, and the message may contain multiple entities.

About four years ago I wrote a small jscript app to parse all of this into XML. That parser relies on a whole bunch of CSV files which define the layout of each type/Sub-type, and another set which defines how to traverse the hierarchy. There is now a need to make this bi-directional and available to real-time applications.

**EDIT:**

BTW, I have no control over the message format. It defined by the US Government. This is a B2B interface and I'm simply a consumer.

Comment: So the short, unfortunate answer is that I don't think anything like this exists. Although, I wonder if you need to interoperate between two languages, why not use soap? That should be supported by pretty much anything.

Comment: If the XML tool still works, I would definitely go with that. you can deserialize XML into CLR objects easily. Im not aware of anything that will deserialize these type of fixed position stuff

Comment: If your messages had fixed length with fixed structure, then I would say .NET has a built-in solution for that. But in your case I think you have to handle all the parsing yourself (I had to do something similar on a TCP server which was receiving different types of messages).

Comment: The XML parser is ugly, but the biggest problem is its only one way, it will generate XML from the fixed format messages but I cannot generate the fixed format from XML with it. Going the other way is much more complex because of the need to validate that the class data will fit in the fixed format.